# How to calculate the coefficients on the original variables after engineering an interaction variable that is uncorrelated to the original variables?

Tags: r, regression, interaction, feature-engineering, linear-algebra

$$x = (0,1,0,1)$$
$$y = (0,0,1,1)$$
$$z = x*y = (0,0,0,1)$$
$$r = \beta_0 + \beta_1x + \beta_2y + \beta_3z + \epsilon$$

Each $\epsilon_i$ is some error term with zero expected value.

Alternatively, we could define some other regression equation, using an interaction term engineered to be uncorrelated with the original variables:

$$x' = x$$
$$y' = y$$
$$z' = -2(z - proj_{x'}(z) - proj_{y'}(z)) = (0,1,1,0)$$
$$r = \beta_0' + \beta_1'x' + \beta_2'y' + \beta_3'z' + \epsilon$$

However, I am not interested in the effect sizes and magnitudes of $x'$, $y'$, and $z'$. I am interested in the effect sizes and magnitudes of the original $x$, $y$, and $z$!

How can I recover the $\beta$ coefficients from the $\beta'$ coefficients that I will estimate explicity via `lm(r ~ x_ + y_ + z_)` (I use underscores instead of primes in R)? Does this even make sense?

I tried doing something, got lost in a bunch of Gaussian elimination, and got an answer that does not check out when I fit `L_ <- lm(r ~ x_ + y_ + z_)` and `L <- lm(r ~ x + y + z)` in `R`.

My concern is with the exact problem coded below, and I think I figured it out, though I am curious about the idea in more generality, too. In particular, what is the (linear?) algebra to recover $\beta$ from $\beta'?$

```
set.seed(2021)
N <- 100

project <- function(u, v){
    numerator <- sum(u * v)
    denominator <- sum(u * u)
    u2 <- u * numerator / denominator
    return(u2)
}

x <- rep(c(0, 1), 2*N)
y <- rep(c(0, 0, 1, 1), N)
z <- x * y
#
x_ <- x
y_ <- y
z_ <- z - project(x_, z) - project(y_, z); z_ <- -2*z_

d <- data.frame(x, y, z)
d_ <- data.frame(x_, y_, z_)
cor(d)  # not mutually uncorrelated
cor(d_) # mutually uncorrelated

e <- rnorm(length(x))
r <- x + y + z + e

L <- lm(r ~ x + y + z)
L_ <- lm(r ~ x_ + y_ + z_)

(summary(L_)$coef[2,1] + summary(L_)$coef[4,1]) - summary(L)$coef[2,1] # basically zero
(summary(L_)$coef[3,1] + summary(L_)$coef[4,1]) - summary(L)$coef[3,1] # basically zero
(-2 * summary(L_)$coef[4,1]) - summary(L)$coef[4,1]                    # basically zero
```

Comment: I do not understand the question or the operations you are performing at the outset. One reason is that $z^\prime$ is *not* orthogonal to $x$ or $y,$ so I can't fathom what you might mean by "$proj$."  Another reason is that the question in the title is easily answered: when you incorporate additional explanatory variables orthogonal to the original explanatory variables, the original coefficient estimates do not change. Finally, you seem to be asking various different questions: is your concern about orthogonality or merely about linear changes of variables?

Comment: @whuber I said orthogonal but meant uncorrelated. I think I changed all of the instances of orthogonal. // Yes, I mean the (linear) transformation of the feature space.  (This is the first that I have thought of it that way. Perhaps I will make progress working on it like that.)

Comment: First, your feature space includes a constant vector for the parameter $\beta_0.$ Second, when you write the model in the form $$E[y]=X\beta$$ (columns of $X$ are features), and create new features $Z=XA$ for some invertible $4\times 4$ matrix $A,$ the same model can be written $$E[y]=X(\operatorname{Id})\beta=X(AA^{-1})\beta=(XA)(A^{-1})\beta=Z(A^{-1}\beta).$$ The coefficients of $Z$ must be $A^{-1}\beta.$